# multiple pip installed: what can I remove?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have multiple pip(s) installed, but I would be fine with just two (one for python2 and the other for python3).

```
user@pc:~$ pip# tab completion list
pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.5  
user@pc:~$ for i in {"pip","pip2","pip2.7","pip3","pip3.5"}; do $i --version; done;
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
pip 9.0.1 from /home/jaky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
pip 9.0.1 from /home/jaky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

I have the doubt they could be aliases links to the same bin, because if I try to remove {pip2,pip2.7} pip(s) want to remove ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip, while if I try to remove {pip,pip3,pip3.5} pip(s) want to remove /usr/local/python3.5/dist-packages/pip.

However, when I search for them I find different binaries:

```
user@pc:~$ ll /usr/local/bin | grep pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      205 Nov  9 17:56 pip*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      204 Oct 10 20:49 pip2*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      204 Oct 10 20:49 pip2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      205 Nov  9 17:56 pip3*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      205 Nov  9 17:56 pip3.5*
```

Answer (score 1):

remove all

> apt-get autoremove pip*

install what you want.